# Storing RESTful data (LoopBack)

Tags: rest, storage

I have decided to use LoopBack framework for my new api application. Actually, I can't understand where all these data is stored. When I use an API data is stored to a database like MYSQL,Oracle?

Comment: what are you trying to ask?

Comment: I can't understand where the data of an api is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Loopback provides various "connectors" so you can plugin your favourite database to store your data. 
See here: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Connecting+models+to+data+sources

To start with, for simplicity and development you can make use of the built in "memory" connector which stores your data in memory and gets wiped every time you restart the node process. A useful tip I've found is that you can pass a setting to have it save a file which I find quite handy for development. https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Memory+connector#Memoryconnector-Datapersistence

When you have decided which database you need to use, you can install the connector for that database from npm.

Each of the strongloop supported connectors have their own documentation pages in the loopback docs. Eg. MySql https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/MySQL+connector

The general process for installing a connector is to first npm install it (except the "memory" connector which is built in)

```
$ npm install loopback-connector-mysql --save
```

And then in configure it in /server/datasources.json

```
"mydb": {
    "name": "mydb",
    "connector": "mysql"
}
```

Generally, you don't tend to manage your database data structure, you define models in loopback and then use the methods "automigrate" and "autoupdate" to have loopback manage the data structures for you. Lots of useful info on that here: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+a+database+schema+from+models

One tool I've found pretty handy is loopback-db-migrate which allows you to create migrations files and run them. https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-db-migrate